# Why is Web Deploy using the wrong account?

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-integration, ntlm, webdeploy

I've verified that Web Deploy works (using NTLM authorization) when I fire it from Visual Studio on my local machine. Now I want my build server to auto-deploy (if appropriate) every night. I'm using Jenkins on the build server, and I've granted the account access in IIS on the remote machine. My parameters to MSBuild are as follows:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true  
/p:Configuration=Debug  
/p:Platform=x86  
/p:PublishProfile=DEV  
/p:AuthType=NTLM  
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True  
/p:Username=
```

The `DEV` publish profile specifies my DEV server which uses a self-signed certificate thus necessitating an untrusted certificate. The `NTLM` and blank username should use the current user/account to connect.

**However**, the Jenkins' job's MSBuild step fails with this error

> msdeploy error ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED: Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer ("DEV-SERVER") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the site.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)

When I look at the IIS logs on DEV-SERVER, I see the following:

> 2016-01-06 23:55:10 159.212.19.186 HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 - 159.212.19.123 - 401 2 5 0
>   2016-01-06 23:55:10 159.212.19.186 HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 CO\BUILD-SERVER$ 159.212.19.123 - 401 2 64 78

I was expecting to see CO\jenkins, the account Jenkins is running under, instead of CO\BUILD-SERVER$. (And what's with the $ on the end?) Am I correct in thinking the wrong account is being used? What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: CO\BUILD-SERVER$ is the machine account of your build server. If you have a slave running on that machine, is it running as a windows service? If so it's probably running as "System"

Comment: @JamesReed You call it. I verified with the people who set up Jenkins. They've manually been running it under the CO\jenkins account, but the build server restarted and the Windows service automatically starts it up under the System account. They switched the account the service starts up under, and that solved my problem, but apparently there's some issue with running Selenium tests. I'll investigate that separately. Thanks a lot! If you want to make an answer and include this resolution and drawback, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CO\BUILD-SERVER$ is the machine account of your build server.

If you have a slave running on that machine, is it running as a windows service? If so it's probably running as "System"

Also re Selenium tests, if the tests are running on the build server then the service may need to set to run interactively so that the tests can run against a UI.